# How to store data from macbook pro 2011 that wont turn ON

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, macbook-pro

It could be hard disk or something, the macbook wont turn on. I dont suspect harddisk though. I would like to back up the data from my hard drive. I am going to open it but can someone guide me how to interface it to my other Laptop (Windows) via us or other means, how to interface it to retrieve my data, assuming that the hard disk is ok.

Answer (score 2):

If it won't turn on at all, you will need to remove the drive and connect it to a USB to SATA dongle/enclosure.

This will provide a physical interface to the drive, but unfortunately Windows doesn't natively speak HFS+, which is the file system on your mac drive.  You might be able to use [hfsexplorer](http://catacombae.org/hfsx.html) to read the data from the drive.

Comment: I have another macbook air that I can use. I am not sure if Macbook Pro's have the same interface as harddrives in PCs?

Comment: Afaik Macbook Airs have SSD Harddrives, therefore it's propably another plug. But I wouldn't recommend to open your macbook air OR pro if you don't really have to. And you definitely can avoid one of it - sata enclosures are like 30 $ or so!

Comment: I already talked to Apple Care and they are going to repair it. I just have to save my data, I have to open it. There is no harm.